# Is it possible to compile a go binary that runs an external python script?

Tags: python, go, binaries

I'm planning to write a python script that executes a machine learning algorithm. But, I need a go binary to implement it as a server extension (chirpstack server). Is it possible to compile a go binary using go code that executes an external python script ?

Comment: Yes. Use a `*Cmd` from the `os/exec` package. Create one using `exec.Command()`: https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Command

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.